# Django haystack using_backends is empty in the RealtimeSignalProcessor

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-cms

I've got `aldryn_search` setup on a few Django CMS sites with `django-haystack` powering that search functionality with elastic search.

When it came to maintaining my search index I found the real time processor & set that up;

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

And after reading the docs assumed this would hook in to all save & delete signals in django and update the haystack index appropriately. However I'm seeing errors coming through Sentry which would suggest there are stale items in the index so I assume then the delete signal isn't removing old objects (no longer in the db) from the index;

```
haystack in _get_object
Object could not be found in database for SearchResult '<SearchResult: djangocms_text_ckeditor.text (pk=u'237')>'.
```

Is there further functionality/configuration options within haystack to avoid this or is it better practice to implement celery tasks to run periodically to run `update_index -r` commands to maintain the index?

**Update**

Digging in to the signal processor, the `using_backends` list is empty while using the Simple backend or Elastic Search. This is obviously why I'm not seeing this feature working as expected. Why would this be empty?

Comment: what do you mean by `old objects`? the ones that were deleted from database?

Comment: @JohnyStark Yeah things that are deleted from the database. I'll admit I don't know much about how the index works or what exactly it stores, but I assume it keeps primary keys or something. So if an object is deleted from the Db I'd assume it'd be removed by the `RealtimeSignalProcessor` from the index.

Comment: Can you please override `handle_delete` as decribed [here](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signal_processors.html#custom-signalprocessors) and put `print` statement inside. And then try to delete some object and see if that statement was printed?

Comment: @JohnyStark I'm not getting any output from save or delete. Tried to add breakpoints in PyCharm also but it doesn't seem to be getting triggered. So thats my problem! `RealtimeSignalProcessor.setup()` is being called however. So perhaps it's the signal connection that fails.

Comment: You have `models.signals.post_delete.connect(self.handle_delete)` in `setup()` right?

Comment: @JohnyStark yes, essentially rather than subclass the `RealtimeSignalProcessor` I've copied the signals in to my project to make things easier. As I say, the setup runs as expected, I've stepped through some of the calls & can't see why those method aren't being picked up.

Comment: Sorry man, run out of ideas :(

Comment: @JohnyStark Thanks. You've given me something to run with so I'll try to setup my own class & connect to my models specifically to see if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79102/discussion-between-marksweb-and-johnystark).